# How to exceute bash script from pyspark

Tags: bash, pyspark

I have huge number of csv files which I am processing via bash.

Is there a way that i can call the bash script file from pyspark and then generate a RDD out of that?

Comment: Start with showing some code on what (or) how `pyshark` works? Is it called from command-line? some more information would be useful

Comment: Used subprocess call. it worked

Comment: Ad: _Used subprocess call. it worked_ You can answer your own question, too If you solved the problem  (and add with more details)., It could help for others.

Answer (score 1):

Used subprocess.call to trigger the bash code.

```
subprocess.call("run.bash", shell=True)
```